# Not Able to Debug the Code using test cases

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, junit

[image][image]I've an application jar files which acts as server. Any client end application can connect with it using TCP socket connection. Now it is running this application using command line as is executable jar application.

I'm writing test cases for this server application. So I run the server jar application and execute the test. Test case make a socket connection with the server application and sent request. Server application sents back the response accordingly. This works perfect.

Debug: Scenario
I'm able to debug the test code means what request it is sending and what response getting from server application.
[image]
**Problem: 
I'm not able to debug the server application source code. Can anybody please help me on this? It will also be OK if I can make the code debug using another client request except unit test but unit test will be great.**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPCG9.png)

About the pictures:
testCase: sendRequest() makes connection using socket

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: To be able to debug the server side code you need the server project in your IDE and start the server in debug mode.

Comment: Many Thanks @Vanje. I missed a very obvious step.

Answer (score 1):

You are running the server code outside of IntelliJ IDEA from the jar file, so you can't debug its code in this mode.

There are 2 options:

- Create a new Run/Debug configuration for the server code in the IDE and start it in Debug mode
- Use **Remote** debug configuration to connect to the server running externally (you will need to adjust the VM options in the command line and use the parameters suggested by the IDE to start the server in debug mode in the console).